# Limited shell for debian

Tags: ssh, debian, shell

I'm looking into a limited shell option for Debian. The idea is to have a shell with limited access and commands for specific users. The user would log in to this shell and have limited access(visibility) to folders/binaries.

I've looked into **rbash**(easy to bypass) and **lshell**(deprecated). I've also played with chroot jail but it is not the ideal solution.

Does anybody know of another solution?

Comment: product recommendations are off topic. Try [unix.se] or [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

From wiki.

```
The restricted mode of the Bourne shell sh, and its POSIX workalikes, is used when the interpreter is invoked in one of the following ways:

sh -r    note that this conflicts with the "read" option in some sh variants
rsh    note that this may conflict with the remote shell command, which is also called rsh on some systems
The restricted mode of Bash is used when Bash is invoked in one of the following ways:

rbash
bash -r
bash --restricted

Similarly KornShell's restricted mode is produced by invoking it thus:

rksh
ksh -r
```

You just need to use one of them, install and link with the session. Also note that restricted shell is not secure.

Comment: From my original post:"I've looked into rbash(easy to bypass) and lshell(deprecated)."